# display code results in windows form textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to get the value produced by the code to be displayed using windows form Textbox. Here is the code that is generating the value:

I want to display the "console:writeline" using a form designer textbox (private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;)

```
public static void TestGetRunSummaryResult()
    {

        // create project
        string requestCreateProjectUri = OpenApiUri + string.Format(CreateProjectUri, "xml");
        HttpWebResponse responseCreateProject =
            (HttpWebResponse)
            _CallPostApi(requestCreateProjectUri, typeof(NewProjectItem), _GetProjectItem("TestGetRunSummaryResultAPI"));
        int newProjectId = DeserializeHttpWebResponse(responseCreateProject);
        projectListToBeDeleted.Add(newProjectId);

        //Create a Base Run
        string requestCreateBaseRunUri = OpenApiUri + string.Format(CreateBaseRunUri, "xml");
        HttpWebResponse responseCreateBaseRun =
            (HttpWebResponse)
            _CallPostApi(requestCreateBaseRunUri, typeof(NewRunItem), _GetNewRunItem(newProjectId));
        int newRunId = DeserializeHttpWebResponse(responseCreateBaseRun);


        string requestGetRunStatusUri = OpenApiUri + string.Format(GetRunStatus, newRunId, 0, "json");

        int percentStatus = 0;

        while (percentStatus < 100)
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)_CallGetApi(requestGetRunStatusUri);
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            RunStatus runStatus = DataContractJsonDeserialize<RunStatus>(result);
            percentStatus = runStatus.StatusPercentDone;
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}% - {1}", percentStatus, runStatus.DetailedStatus));
        }

        string requestGetRunSummaryResultsUri = OpenApiUri +
                                             string.Format(GetRunSummaryResultsUri, newRunId, 0, "json");
        HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)_CallGetApi(requestGetRunSummaryResultsUri);
        Stream responseStream2 = response2.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(responseStream2);
        string resultSummary = reader2.ReadToEnd();
        RunResultSummary runResultSummary = DataContractJsonDeserialize<RunResultSummary>(resultSummary);

        MessageBox.Show("Building Type: " + runResultSummary.BuildingType);

        //Console.WriteLine("Summary run result for: " + runResultSummary.Runtitle);
        //Console.WriteLine("Location: " + runResultSummary.Location);
        //Console.WriteLine("Building Type: " + runResultSummary.BuildingType);
        //Console.WriteLine("Project Template: " + runResultSummary.ProjectTemplateApplied);
        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Floor Area: {0} {1}", runResultSummary.FloorArea.Value, runResultSummary.FloorArea.Units));
        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Electriciyt Cost: {0} {1}", runResultSummary.ElectricCost.Value, runResultSummary.ElectricCost.Units));
        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Annual Energy Cost: {0} ", runResultSummary.RunEnergyCarbonCostSummary.AnnualEnergyCost));
        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Lifecycle Cost: {0} ", runResultSummary.RunEnergyCarbonCostSummary.LifecycleCost));
        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Annual CO2 Emissions Electric: {0} {1}", runResultSummary.RunEnergyCarbonCostSummary.AnnualCO2EmissionsElectric.Value, runResultSummary.RunEnergyCarbonCostSummary.AnnualCO2EmissionsElectric.Units));
        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Annual CO2 Emissions On site Fuel: {0} {1}", runResultSummary.RunEnergyCarbonCostSummary.AnnualCO2EmissionsOnsiteFuel.Value, runResultSummary.RunEnergyCarbonCostSummary.AnnualCO2EmissionsOnsiteFuel.Units));
        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Annual CO2 Emissions Large SUV Equivalent: {0} {1}", runResultSummary.RunEnergyCarbonCostSummary.AnnualCO2EmissionsLargeSUVEquivalent.Value, runResultSummary.RunEnergyCarbonCostSummary.AnnualCO2EmissionsLargeSUVEquivalent.Units));


        //Assert.AreEqual(runResultSummary.Runtitle, "box model");

    }
```

Comment: What's the issue, do you get any error or you are not getting the expected value?

Comment: "The code that is generating the value" `TestGetRunSummaryResult()` is returning `void`. If I am getting it correctly, you need to return whatever you want from `TestGetRunSummaryResult()` method in order for your `textBox1` to display.

Comment: I am able to get the correct value using a messagebox. for eg. "Building ID: Office" is returned when i use message box. I want the same results displayed on my textbox in the windows form.

Comment: but i am unable to use this.texbox to display since its a static method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a few options:

1.Restructure your code so that your method isn't static. This is probably not a bad option, as static can often be a bad way of structuring your code anyway.

2.Create a static TextBox saying something like

```
static Textbox myTextBox;
```

And then set this to your textbox on form load, and use it instead of Console.WriteLine()

3.Pass in a TextBox in as a parameter

```
public static void TestGetRunSummaryResult(TextBox y)
{
    t.Text = "whatever";
}
```

4.Use a Callback method

If you are using MultiThreading, then don't forget to use TextBox.Invoke() also. (-: